# How to manage string slices with less overhead?

Tags: c++, substring, cstring, slice, stdstring

I'm dealing with giant (up to 2GB) strings and their slices in C++ program. C-style strings seem to be unreliable under such circumstances, but can be sliced trivially (without '\0' at the end). On the other hand, as I understood, std::string::substr copies the slice, therefore I should perform at least one extra addition operation (index + base) per indexing in order to keep memory usage rational.

Comment: So far, this is not a real question. Besides this, can't you do (reading) slicing using iterators?

Comment: I'm searching for a way to slice std::string effectively or confirmation that it is unreal.

Comment: Unreal to slice effectively, i meant.

Answer (score 8):

The most general solution would be to create a slice object, with the
interface you need, and use that.  The slice object could consist of two
iterators, the start and the end.

Comment: And decide what semantics you want for the slices: are the characters in the slice modifiable? If so is modifying the slice supposed to modify the full string? If modifiable but not shared, you need copy-on-write, which is an extra tonne of fun unless you can dig out some old COW implementation of `std::string` and use that (renamed).